# Casting result of Dictionary of objects after Skip and Take

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Dictionary of objects defined like this -

```
Dictionary<string, MyObject> myObjectDictionary
```

I would like to grab items in the Dictionary based of an index and count of items. I am trying to use `Skip` and `Take`. But this requires recasting it back to `Dictionary<string, MyObject>`. How can this be done? Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Here is my code and failed attempt to recast -

```
Dictionary<string, MyObject> myObjectDictionary = FillMyObjectDictionary();

var mySmallerObjectDictionary = myObjectDictionary.Skip(startNumber).Take(count);

//THE FOLLOWING DOES NOT WORK
Dictionary<string, MyObject> myNewObjectDictionary = (Dictionary<string, MyObject>)mySmallerObjectDictionary
```

Comment: You are aware that the contents of `mySmallerObjectDictionary` will be indeterminate? Indexes and Dictionaries do not mix, because the order of enumeration of a Dictionary (or any hashtable structure) is undefined. Do not rely on insertion order being the same as enumeration order. If things work as expected, this is only a coincidence.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, you can create a new dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, MyObject> myNewObjectDictionary =
    myObjectDictionary.Skip(startNumber)
                      .Take(count)
                      .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

However:

- You shouldn't rely on the ordering of a dictionary. It's not clear which items you wish to skip. Consider using `OrderBy` before `Skip`. For example:

  ```
  Dictionary<string, MyObject> myNewObjectDictionary =
      myObjectDictionary.OrderBy(pair => pair.Key)
                        .Skip(startNumber)
                        .Take(count)
                        .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
  ```
- This does *not* preserve any custom equality comparer that was in the original dictionary. Unfortunately that's not exposed anywhere, so you'll just have to know whether or not `FillMyObjectDictionary` uses a custom comparer.

Comment: +10 for "This does not preserve any custom equality comparer that was in the original dictionary"

Answer (score 2):

The result of the `Skip` / `Take` operation will not be an `IDictionary<string, MyObject>`, it will be an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, MyObject>>`.

If you want to convert this back to a dictionary, try calling [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var myNewObjectDictionary = mySmallerObjectDictionary.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```